# Validation accuracy much lower than training accuracy in Keras for text classification

Tags: r, neural-network, keras, text-classification

I am new to Keras and trying to create a model. The issue is that my training accuracy is around 80 percent but the validation accuracy is drastically low at 15 percent. I have 545 rows in my dataset. I have normalized all the input features. Any help on what can be tweaked would be really helpful.

Sharing the complete data and code here

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g8Cmw2bmAI9DnOU-rB4sjsOeBuFp6NUy

```
   #Normalize data

data[,1:(ncol(data)-1)] = normalize(data[,1:(ncol(data)-1)])

data[,ncol(data)] = as.numeric(data[,ncol(data)]) - 1

set.seed(128)

ind = sample(2,nrow(data),replace = T,prob = c(0.7,0.3))

training = data[ind==1,1:(ncol(data)-1)]

test = data[ind==2,1:(ncol(data)-1)]

traintarget = data[ind==1,ncol(data)]

testtarget = data[ind==2,ncol(data)]
# One hot encoding
trainLabels = to_categorical(traintarget)
testLabels = to_categorical(testtarget)
print(testLabels)

model = keras_model_sequential()

model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 150, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(520)) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 50, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dense(units = 9, activation = 'softmax') 


model %>%
  compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam',metrics = 'accuracy')


history = model %>%
  fit(training,
      trainLabels,
      epoch = 300,
      batch_size = 32,
      validation_split = 0.2)

prob = model %>%
  predict_proba(test)

pred = model %>%
  predict_classes(test)

table2 = table(Predicted = pred, Actual = testtarget)

cbind(prob,pred,testtarget)
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a specific programming question that's right for Stack Overflow. If you need general model fitting advice, then you should probably ask over at [datascience.se] or [stats.se].

Comment: @MrFlick - Thanks for the advice. I will post the question in the forums you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Simply put when your model is succeeding at training but not validation it is *overfitting.* The best way to combat this is by a) making sure that your inputs actually predict the outputs because otherwise a large enough model will just memorize the historical data. and b) by adding a dropout layer in your network. Finally, 500 something training samples seems a little low for training a neural network.